# Could not find section 'castle' in the configuration file associated with this domain

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am getting this error when I publish Cuyahoga CMS to localhost.

What can I do? I don't know anything about "castle" or "castle.windsor".

Answer (score 2):

Compare your `web.config` with the one that comes with the Cuyahoga CMS. Your definitley missing some config sections for the Castle Windsor IoC the project depends on. Like:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14402222/4573839), you need to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <castle>
    <components>
    </components>
  </castle>
</configuration>
```

If only add `<section name="castle"...`, I still get error, I add `<castle>...</castle>` then error solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is an assembly that your project depends on (it is an IoC container, but that's irrelevant) and which is looking for a configuration section in your `web.config` file that is missing.

You need to configure it correctly for the error to go.