# configuration file of castle windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

that how my config file looklike:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <!--<configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <castle>-->
    <components>
      <component id="BasicElement" service="ClassLibrary1.ISomething, ClassLibrary1"
                 type="ClassLibrary1s.Something, ClassLibrary1"
                 lifestyle="singleton">
      </component>
    </components>
  <!--</castle>-->
</configuration>
```

when I run my application in F5 i got the error:
**Configuration system failed to initialize**, and the inner exception tells me:
**Unrecognized configuration section components.**

and i see that it consequentially  call the file **Interception.vshost.exe.Config**
although that I explicitly asked him to read other file.

please help!!!

Answer (score 3):

You've commented out the configSection part and the castle parts leaving just the component section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
  <castle>
    <components>
    </components>
  </castle>
</configuration>
```

If you want a blank castle configuration I would suggest something like the above.